# MYSQL query not working with Greek words in where or FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql, find-in-set

There are two records with ABITE and ABİDE name in the database but below query always return ABITE row in the query response because of Greek character in ABİDE.

```
SELECT * FROM `namedetails` WHERE FIND_IN_SET (CitizenName,'ABITE,ABİDE')>0
```

May I know, how we can use the Greek character in where or FIND_IN_SET query?

Comment: What is the collation of your table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen -  I am using utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Let me share it with you. I have added the below codes and it's started rending greek and special character worlds.

```
mysqli_query($link, "SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($link, "SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");
```